# Can't upload file on linux server with MulterJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux

I'm using [MulterJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) for upload files from my Angular project with [Express](https://github.com/expressjs/express) for Server Side.I had test on my development(Windows,Mac OS) on local and network.It can upload normally.but when I put my code on linux server it's can't upload any file in same code. I don't know how to fix this problem. 
Initially I changed permission on destination folder to 777 so that It not work. Please Help ,Sorry for my Bad in English.

On any test PC or Server. I run this project in Server side `npm start` on port 3000

Comment: do you have any error logs?

Answer (score 0):

I solved by my self. I forgot to change API path and route to same with express on Client-Side. Thanks @HRK44